# Run powershell in new window

Tags: powershell

I would like to run new powershell window with parameters. I was trying to run following:

```
powershell -Command "get-date"
```

but everything happens in same console. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell launch script in new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237473/powershell-launch-script-in-new-instance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `start` command. In a CMD prompt, try:

`start powershell -noexit -command "get-date"`

For Start/Run (or Win+r) prompt, try:

`cmd /c start powershell -noexit -command "get-date"`

The `-noexit` will tell Powershell to, well, not to exit. If you omit this parameter, the command will be executed and you are likely to just see a glimpse of a Powershell window. For interactive use, this is a must. For scripts it is not needed.

**Edit:**

`start` is an internal command for CMD. In Powershell it is an alias for `Start-Process`. These are not the same thing.

As for why the window is black, that's because the shortcut for Powershell.exe is configured to set the background blue.

Comment: I run second command from powershell (first one does not work), but new powershell is black. Why this happened?

Comment: Works, but does assume you already have powershell in your path.

Answer (score 12):

To open a new PowerShell Window from PowerShell:

```
Start-Process PowerShell
```

Or my personal favorite:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -WindowStyle Maximized
```

Then you could type`Get-Date`without having to deal with the -ArgumentList's tendency to close itself.  I still haven't found a way to open a new PowerShell process with the -ArgumentList Parameter, without it immediately closing after it runs.  For Instance:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "Get-Date"
```

or simply

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList Get-Date
```

Will Close Immediately after running the process.

In order to get it to wait before closing you could add:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList 'Get-Date; Read-Host "Press Enter"'
```

Since the -Wait Parameter seems to do nothing at all in this case.

FYI - PowerShell Suggested Syntax is actually:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe"
```

But since PowerShell is a standard Windows Application  in the %SystemRoot%\system32 Environment Variables the command line(s) should recognize a simple

```
Powershell
```

Command

Comment: This's more simple answer that I hope from the community. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @t-fred, I was able to get the window to stay open by basically combining your two suggestions.  Start a powershell process which runs powershell with the `-NoExit` arg:
`Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "PowerShell -NoExit 'get-date'"`

#janky

Answer (score 1):

To call a PowerShell (PS) script in a ***second terminal window*** **without exiting**, you can use a script similar to:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "-noexit", "get-date"
```

or if you need to run another script from a specific location:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-command .\local_path\start_server.ps1"
```