# PowerShell - create an automatic script to install chocolatey and dependencies

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to develop a script to automate the installation of some programs and also the development environment. So I thought Chocolatey could help me with that.

How can I create a script to be run in the power shell to install chooclaty and then other applications?

It would be a script to run something like this:

```
# Install Chocolatey
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

#After finish Chocolatey, run the commands:

# install apps
choco install vscode, git, nvm --force -n

# using nvm to install node version
nvm install v14.17.1
nvm use 14.17.1

# install yarn
npm install --global yarn

#install expo
npm install --global expo
```

Any idea how to do this? I would also improve the script to clone the repository, install dependencies with yarn, etc.

Comment: Can you tell me what about your code is not working?

Comment: I get the message "npm is not recognized as an internal command". But I installed node in previous commands. Would it be possible to give a refreh in cmd or else close and open again calling the npm installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could launch your later commands in a new powershell instance like this:

```
start powershell {npm install --global yarn; npm install --global expo}
```

For reference, you can find multiple different ways to do this with different options, depending on your future requirements, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237473/powershell-launch-script-in-new-instance).