# How can I use Windows PowerShell to dynamically "create/monitor/drive/control" another PowerShell instance?

Tags: powershell, shell, automation, scripting

I would like to know how to have one PowerShell instance dynamically control another PowerShell instance:

1. Open a PowerShell instance (ogPS .. *going forward*) and execute a PowerShell script
2. From in the ogPS script, start another PowerShell instance (newPS .. *going forward*)
3. Monitor in ogPS the StdOut & ErrOut of the newPS, allowing ogPS to "watch" the status of commands
4. Drive newPS by sending/streaming new commands to the StdIn of newPS, by responding to when newPS has returned a prompt
5. Control newPS by perhaps "breaking" an operation that is taking too long to respond
6. ogPS should be able to drive the newPS to gracefully exit by sending `exit` to newPS's StdIn

... ideally this would all be async / event driven (but I'll take a polling solution too).

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620390/1327508 to a similar question seems to be able to open a new instance and statically run some command(s); but it's not what I'm looking for.

Similarly, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807020/1327508 opens newPS from ogPS, but that's only a small part of the overall question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: System.IO.Pipes contains some classes for this. Basically it comes down to creating a PipeServerStream and a PipeClientStream and sending data between them. As an alternative you can always use a socket connection on 127.0.0.1 to communicate between both processes

Comment: @bluuf I'll have to do some further research on System.IO.Pipes to see if I can accomplish what I'm looking for, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-PSHostProcessInfo` to see what PS instances are running, and use `Enter-PSHostProcess` to enter that window.

or, if you trying to work with a runspace with a debugger attached you may be able to use the following:

```
get-runspace | Where-object {_.Debugger.InBreakpoint -eq $true} | Debug-Runspace
```

pardon the messiness, im on my way out of work.

Comment: I'll have to do some further research on your suggestions to see if I can accomplish what I'm looking for, thanks for the suggestion.